# UVa online judge #458 time limit exceeded

Tags: java, performance, algorithm

I am trying to solve [UVa problem 458 - decoder](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/external/4/458.pdf) and I came up with the following algorithm which gives me the correct output for the sample input data, but runs longer than allowed.

```
    public class Decoder {

    public void decoder() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (sc.hasNext()) {

            String line = sc.nextLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {

                if(line.charAt(i)>=32 && line.charAt(i)<=126)
                System.out.print((char) (line.charAt(i) - 7));

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

## What I've looked into

Well I have read the [forums](http://acm.uva.es/board/search.php?st=0&sk=t&sd=d&sr=posts&sid=0eab2b6827eb8ef3b7481238919bdbcf&keywords=458) and most of the solutions were pretty similar, I have been researching if there was a way of avoiding the **for** loop which is running through the string and printing out the new char. But this loop is inevitable, this algorithm's time complexity is always going to be n^2.

The problem also mentions to only change ASCII printable values, which is why I set the condition to check if its greater than or equal to 32 and 126. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) that is the range of printable values.

http://ideone.com/XkByW9

Comment: Perhaps processing the whole line and only then printing it would be faster than decoding and printing each character separately.

Comment: You're sure you're generating the correct output - that's really why your program is failing, right? The reason I ask is that you not only restrict changing values to ASCII printable characters, but you restrict *printing* to ASCII printable characters, minus 7. Should you be subtracting first, and then printing if the result is within the correct range?

Comment: @Patrick87 it exceeds time limit the answers are correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Avoid decoding the stream to characters. It's ok to use bytes if you only have to support ASCII.
2. Read and write the data in big chunks to avoid function/system call overhead.
3. Avoid unnecessary allocations. Currently you are allocating new String for every line.
4. Do not split the input into lines to avoid bad performance for very small lines.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    while (true) {
        int len = System.in.read(buffer);
        if (len <= 0) {
            break;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            ...
        }
        System.out.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
}
```

It will process the input as you would normally process a binary file. For every iteration, it will read up to 2048 bytes into a buffer, process them and write them to standard output. Program will end when EOF is reached and [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) returns -1. 2048 is usually a good buffer size, but you might want to try different sizes and see which one works best.

Comment: hey that code is really interesting but I am not sure exactly what its doing. So youre basically setting an array of bytes as (what made you choose 2048 has max ?) and then you read the system in with the buffer size ? I played with it and it works really well but I dont know how ?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza how can i add new line ?

Answer (score 1):

Never use `Scanner` for long inputs. The scanner is unbelievably slower than other means of reading input in Java, such as `BufferedReader`. This UVa problem looks like one with a quite long input.